# Local site renders differently on server

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I've a site johnmcnameeplastering.co.uk that's been up a while and worked okay and should look like the sample pages below (homepage and another page). For some reason after uploading a revised version of full.css yesterday the site now looks messed up online. My first thought was an incorrect css path somewhere but I can't locate the problem. really hoping someone can help me out.

Thanks Antony

[image]

Comment: Check the console & network tab.

Comment: Thanks SLaks - much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Seems like you uploaded the file with the wrong permissions. This problem was easily located by using the developer tools and its dedicated console. Every browser has such a tool, so try it out. It'll help you a lot in the future.

Comment: Hi Bram - thank you for responding. I've got as far as opening the file permissions dialog for the css folder on the server but wasn't sure if the check boxes are correct?

Comment: Ah - I set the bootstrap.min.css permisison from 673 to 755 and I think it's worked :-)